# Remove 5 seconds delay to flag comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Few days ago I was encouraged by a Mod to review and remove the unneeded comments as a maintenance task.

> FYI, and this goes for everyone, if you have spare cycles it would be appreciated if you could go through your list of comments, removing anything that is old or irrelevant. Flag others comments as you go, and we'll get them cleaned up, too.

After a while, I've detected that comments can only by flagged every 5 seconds.

Well, consider a question with a lot of comments, (f.e. 15), you must flag the first, wait 5 seconds, flag the second, wait 5 sec. again, and so on.

It could be interesting to remove this delay, maybe for users with a minimum reputation, or users that got review badges.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Much appreciated. Hope we get the go for this feature request.

Comment: flagging lower than 5 seconds can lead to massive abuse and nobody wnats that, there can't be that much comments here that warrant deletion and even if there are you will reach your task even at this rate

Comment: @nbk Huh? If the delay is removed for users with a certain minimum reputation there will be very little abuse. And with a lot of comments you quickly bump into this limit. It's extremely annoying and unnecessary.

Comment: FYI, there have been quite a few posts on the network Meta about this. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Comment+rate+limit

Comment: Personally, I've ran into the rate limit many times before becoming a mod, and just put up with it.  I agree it's painful.

Comment: @MaxVernon thanks, I've only searched on DBA meta.

Comment: @Colin'tHart as far as i am concerned, there are to many comments removed already a 5 second delay gives you time to think twice about is it really necessary to remove that coment. On stack exchange the commnst a a think of low quality , but there are some major knowledge behind. i sue the flagging system quite rarely, as i don't like the politics behind the concept, so i never i my live encountered that delay and if  it ave forgiotten about it. NS lao lower rep user are already moaning about their restrictions, why goven them more to claim

Comment: @nbk: Different people have different views on these matters, and some use flagging, including comment flagging, very often, while others, like you, quite rarely, and that's perfectly fine, we don't have to have the same opinion on everything. However, *because* you are using this feature rarely, you are probably not in a good position to judge whether a 5-second delay is a positive thing or not. Some comments can be easily evaluated as noise, and when there are many of them, having to wait 5 seconds before flagging each individual comment is really, really annoying.

Comment: @nbk comments are ephemeral.  You can expect almost all comments to be deleted at *some* point in the future.  Even a comment that has an actual answer embedded in it will be deleted if not converted into an answer.

Comment: @MaxVernon this ismy major issue with comments, that they are to fast deleted, and i know that the deletion can happen at any tome, this is one of the things i  **don't** like,